# NoReverseMatch at / Error during template rendering

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-urls

When I open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` which is `home.html`, I am getting:

> NoReverseMatch at / and Reverse for 'exam-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['exam/(?P[^/]+)$']

I think the error is due to `<str:pk>` in `urls.py`.

The **urls.py** file is below:

```
from . import views
from .views import ExamListView, ExamDetailView

app_name='map'
urlpatterns = [
    path("", ExamListView.as_view(), name='map-home'),
    path("exam/<str:pk>", ExamDetailView.as_view(), name="exam-detail"),
    path("login_student/", views.login_student, name='map-login'),
    path("register_student", views.register_student, name='map-register'),
    path('add_student/', views.add_student, name='add_student'),
    path('front/', views.front, name="front"),
]
```

**models.py**:

```
    subject = models.TextField(primary_key = True, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "map/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <p>WELCOME HOME</p>
    {% for exam in exams %}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'map:exam-detail' exam.subject %}">{{ exam }} </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'map/main.css' %}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title> MAP PAGE </title>
    {% endif %} 
</head>
<body>
        <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">Project M.A.P</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'map:map-home' %}">Home</a>  <!-- no hardcoded links -->
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'map:map-home' %}">About</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
              {% else %}
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'map:map-register' %}">Student</a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                        {{ message }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>


     <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>[enter image description here][1]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

from . models import Student, Exam
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

def home(request):
    context = {
        'exams': Exam.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'map/home.html', context)

class ExamListView(ListView): #class based views
    model = Exam
    template_name = 'map/home.html'  #<app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'exams'
    ordering = ['subject'] #['-exam']


class ExamDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Exam
```

Comment: url `exam-detail` is not found. Please either add this URL in urls.py or if this is not valid then check the code where this call has been made

Comment: Please try below in url and see if it fix your issue. path("<str:pk>/", ExamDetailView.as_view(), name="exam-detail"),

Comment: **Reverse for 'exam-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<pk>[^/]+)$']**  This is my error.  I tried **path("<str:pk>/", ExamDetailView.as_view(), name="exam-detail")** too. The problem is due to improper argument passing. But I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In
python manage.py shell

```
from my_app_name.models import Exam

exam = Exam()
exam.subject = ""
exam.save()
```

I have executed these lines. and I also created exams for subject like "google", "english",..

Now `Exam.objects.all()` returns

```
<QuerySet [<Exam: google>, <Exam: english>, <Exam: >]>
```

The problem is due to having a string of length zero as subject for one of the exam object. Now I deleted that exam using `Exam.objects.get(subject="").delete()`. Problem solved.

```
{% url 'map:exam-detail' exam.subject %}
```

or

```
{% url 'map:exam-detail' exam %}
```

or

```
{% url 'map:exam-detail' exam.pk %}
```

all these are working now because all are returning the subject. But `{% url 'map:exam-detail' exam.id %}` **won't work**. Because I have made **subject** as **primary_key** in the **Exam model**, so Exam model don't have an attribute id(which is added by default when no primary_key is mentioned).

thinking about why it has accepted the empty string as a subject, though I have defined it as primary_key. 
Then I wanna read about django.db.models.TextField and just keyed help(TextField) and got

```
TextField(verbose_name=None, name=None, primary_key=False, max_length=None, unique=False, blank=False, null=False, db_index=False, rel=None, default=<class 'django.db.models.fields.NOT_PROVIDED'>, editable=True, serialize=True, unique_for_date=None, unique_for_month=None, unique_for_year=None, choices=None, help_text='', db_column=None, db_tablespace=None, auto_created=False, validators=(), error_messages=None)
```

Now tried **validators**...
The follow up problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60419516/how-to-use-validators-in-django)

***Thank you all***
Mounika

Answer (score 0):

You missed exam.pk in the home.html
Update your code in this manner,

```
<div class="article-metadata">
<a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'map:exam-detail' 
exam.pk %}">{{ exam }} </a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I tried this. still getting the same error. NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'exam-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['exam/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'exam-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['exam/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']
Exception Location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677

Comment: in your views.py file you created a class ExamDetailView and as you can see your this class is only working on model field, there is no template_name field. Do you even created an html or template file for DetailView ?? Also i suggest you to use reverse_lazy. You can see my views.py file to know how its done, link->  https://github.com/YashMarmat/Blog-App-django-v3/blob/master/blog/views.py