# How to use validators in django

Tags: python, sql, django, validation, django-models

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

```
def validate_subject(value):
    if value.isalnum():
        raise ValidationError(_('%(value)s is not valid. Please use alphanumneric characters as subject names'), params={'value': value},)
```

```
class Exam(models.Model):  #Exam can have many questions
    subject = models.TextField(primary_key=True, unique = True, validators = [validate_subject])  #make it to reject a string of length 0

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

I want this code to raise an error when I keyed the following

```
from my_app.models import Exam
exam = Exam()
exam.subject = ""
exam.save()
```

Why Iam not getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validators do *not* run when you `.save()` an object, this is mainly done for performance reasons. You can call the [**`.full_clean()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) to validate the model object:

```
from my_app.models import Exam

exam = Exam()
exam.subject = ''
exam.full_clean()
exam.save()
```

A `ModelForm` will also clean the model object, so the validators will run if you create or update a model through a `ModelForm`.